# How to know the element contain namespace(xmlns) or not?

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

```
<xxx1 xmlns="hello">
    <xxx2>
        <xxx3>
            <name>rule_1</name>
        </xxx3>
    </xxx2>
</xxx1>
```

I select node by "//*[namespace-uri()='hello']/*[local-name()='name']"

It should get `//hello:xxx1/xxx2/xxx3/name` , and it does.

Now I try to get element . In reality, I don't know how much parent for `<name>` will get `<xxx1>`;

I try this code

```
node.getParent().getNamespaceURI() = "Hello"
```

and increase `getParent()` amount to get `<xxx1>`

But the first time I call  `<xxx3>.getNamespaceURI()` it returns `true`.

Is the namespace inherited?

How to get the element has or not has xmlns?

---

Sorry for my question was not clearly.

I'm trying to get the element which is the first declared namespace "hello".

```
<xxx1 xmlns="hello">
    <xxx2>
        <xxx3>
```

this three node which one is contained `xmlns="hello"`, 'cause `<xxx2>` and `<xxx3>` was not declare `xmlns` in the label.

Comment: your question is unclear .. can you please explain with better example to see what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Yes, namespaces are sort of inherited, but the terminology normally used is that, in your example, the `<name>` element is in the *scope* of the namespace declaration `xmlns="hello"`, so the `<name>`element will be *in* the `hello` namespace.

With `DOM4J`, you can test whether an element is in a namespace or not like this:

```
boolean hasNamespace(Element e) {
    return e.getNamespaceURI().length() > 0;
}
```

If the element is not in any namespace, `getNamespaceURI()` returns an empty string.

I guess that you want to select the `<name>` element, but you don't know at which level it be, i.e. how many parents it will have. You can always use this XPath expression:

```
    Node node = doc.selectSingleNode("//*[namespace-uri() = 'foo' and local-name() = 'name']");
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad express, I'm trying to get `<xxx1>` element , I want to get `<name>` 's parent which contain(write in the label) `xmlns="hello"`.

Comment: Do you to want get the furthest ancestor element of  the `<name>` element that declares the namespace `hello`?